# When the website URL is typed in, the .htaccess must instantly go to the correct file & path

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, ftp

When the website URL is typed in correctly like: `https://example.amsterdam`

It should instantly change the URL to: `https://example.amsterdam/dist/index.php`

I already tried to solve this problem with creating a `DirectoryIndex dist/index.php` The only clue with trying to fix it like this is it only loads up the page and not the correct path in the URL. So when the file is open and you click on a button,

the `HREF` doesn't work anymore because the path is not correct.

So I basically want to open the file in the correct path in the URL. Instantly when the user types the URL

My current `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

[image: Current Filestack]

Comment: Why not just set your `DocumentRoot` directory to the `dist` directory in your Apache configuration?  The only directory that needs get transferred to your webserver is usually your `dist` directory.  You usually want to keep your `src` and other files out of the document root for security and to keep your website clean.

Comment: `index.php` is never meant to show up in any URL.  You should never redirect to or link to an index document.  Index document names are meant to stay hidden.  They are just the default name chosen to power the content for a directory request.  You should always prefer to link or redirect to the URL ending in slash that you get by taking off `index.php`

Comment: "the HREF doesn't work anymore because the path is not correct." - What URLs are you using in your links? By "redirecting" the request to the subdirectory it sounds as if you are working around other issues. Should the `/dist` subdirectory even be visible in the URL (as Stephen suggests)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does sound like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), as "redirecting" to the `DirectoryIndex` document is generally not desirable and sounds like you are compensating for other issues. eg. Using relative URL-paths in your links (and to static assets), exposing the `/dist/` subdirectory when this should be hidden, etc.

Anyway, to answer your question specific question...

> I already tried to solve this problem with creating a `DirectoryIndex dist/index.php`

If you specifically want to redirect the request (rather than an internal subrequest) then you can set `DirectoryIndexRedirect on` in addition to the `DirectoryIndex` directive. In other words:

```
DirectoryIndex dist/index.php
DirectoryIndexRedirect on
```

The above would trigger a 302 (temporary) redirect. You can use the http status code `301` for a permanent redirect. See [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindexredirect) for other options.

Note that the `DirectoryIndex` directive applies to any directory that you request. So, if you were to request `/dist/` then the above directive would cause mod_dir to look for `/dist/dist/index.php` (since you had specified a relative path). You could use `DirectoryIndex /dist/index.php` (a root-relative path) to always serve the same file, regardless of whether a subdirectory is requested.

Alternatively, to *only* redirect the document root then use mod_rewrite. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /dist/index.php [R,L]
```

Again, the above is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Use `R=301` for a permanent redirect.

Although you shouldn't need `index.php` to be present in the (visible) URL, so just redirect the root to `/dist/` and let a standard `DirectoryIndex` do the work. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule ^$ /dist/ [R,L]
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindexredirect
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule